# Looping through a panda dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

My variable noExperience1 is a dataframe
I am trying to go through this loop:

```
num = 0

for row in noExperience1:
 if noExperience1[row+1] - noExperience1[row] > num:
    num = noExperience1[row+1] - noExperience1[row]

print(num)
```

My goal is to find the biggest difference in y values from one x value to the next. But I get the error that the line of my if statement needs to be a string and not an integer. How do I fix this so I can have a number?

Comment: Does your dataframe have just 1 column? Could you please provide sample data and expected result?

Comment: There is likely a way to do this without an explicit loop. Could you post a few lines of example data from your DataFrame?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can't directly access a row of dataframe using indexing. We need to use loc or iloc for it. I had just solved the problem stated by you.

```
`noExperience1=pd.read_csv("../input/data.csv")#reading CSV file
num=0
for row in range(1,len(noExperience1)): #iterating row in all rows of DF
    if int(noExperience1.loc[row]-noExperience1.loc[row-1]) > num:
        num = int(noExperience1.loc[row]-noExperience1.loc[row-1])
print(num)`
```

Note:
1.Column Slicing : DataFrame[ColName] ==> will give you all enteries of specified column. 
2.Row Slicing: DataFrame.loc[RowNumber] ==> will give you a complete row of specified row numbe.RowNumber starts with 0.

Hope this helps.